# Play 2 framework many-to-many relation better design

Tags: java, database, jpa, playframework-2.0, many-to-many

In my app I have different `User`s and `Item`s, so each user can pick many items.

In the tutorial I have learned about `@ManyToMany` annotation.

```
@Entity
public class Item extends Model {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    public List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
```

But second option I can think of is to define a separate class for User-to-Item relation so I can add additional information like date and time.

```
@Entity
public class ItemUserRel extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;

    public User user;
    public Item item;

    //additional information
    public Date date;

    ...
```

**Which of both options is better design and why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced a similar issue a while ago. I also had to deal with a model `User` and the model `Group`. My requirements were:

A user can have *n* `readable` and *n* `writable` Groups. These permissions must be stored in a third table (not in User and not in Group table). But also additional properties like `authorisedBy` and 'authorisedOn'. So **@ManyToMany** did not worked for, because I had no *real* control of it. Also the additional properties makes it hard to map via JPA.

Perhaps other designs are possible but I (still) think that introducing a new class `UserGroup` would be best. This class has `@ManyToOne` relation to a single `User`.

I end up defining these three models:

1. User
2. Group - *General information about the group model*
3. UserGroup - *Containing additional fields like: `permissions`, `authorisedBy`, `authorisedOn` etc.*

On my User model, I would have getter `getUserGroups()` but also `getPersonalGroup()` which is basically one (personal) instance of `Group` in `getUserGroups()` but where the `createdBy` and `authorisedBy` is the same user.

I found this design much more maintainable by me and more clear. Also this design helped me to create a comfortable user interface, where the administrator can manage and change permissions for UserGroups.

Perhaps more useful information

- [Mapping many-to-many association table with extra column(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127129/mapping-many-to-many-association-table-with-extra-columns)
- [How Do I Create Many to Many Hibernate Mapping for Additional Property from the Join Table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table)