# Hibernate one to many relationship with join table with addition columns in join table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entity-relationship

I am looking for a way to have a @OneToMany relation between two tables and having extra attributes in the join table and I am not able to find much useful examples around. Sorry if this sounds lame but can any suggest me a good way for it.

Comment: you should not use join table for 1 to m relation

Comment: Can you provide some more detail?  What do your tables look like?  What would you like your join table to look like?  What have you tried?

Comment: you mean many to many relation. If so here is a way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have additional columns in the join table, it's not a join table anymore, and you need a way to get and set values in these columns. So the answer is simple: the table needs to be mapped as an entity.

For example, let's say you have a Person entity and an Address entity. And the person has several addresses. Now let's say each address must be categorized: home address, professional address, etc. To be able to map the category of the address, you need an entity:

```
Person 1 ---> N CategorizedAddress 1 ---> 1 Address
```

And `CategorizedAddress` would have a property of type Address, and a property containing the category.