# Mapping many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have a **many-to-many** relationship :

`customer`, `product`, `customer_product` with extra column `quantity`

i want to map them with hibernate my question is :

what i will loose if i just map them normally like two **one-to-many** ?
`customer_product` will have just one primary key (`id_customer_product`) and not a composite primary key (`id_product` + `id_customer`)

`customer` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", catalog = "XX")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    private Set customer_product = new HashSet<Customer_Product>(0);
}
```

`product` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "product", catalog = "XX")
public class Customer implements java.io.Serializable {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product")
    private Set customer_product = new HashSet<customer_product>(0);
}
```

`customer_product` Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer_product", catalog = "XX")
public class Customer_Product implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "ID_customer_product")
    private Integer ID_customer_product;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_customer")
    private Customer customer;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_product")
    private Product product;

}
```

Or i have to make like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table/10301484#10301484) and make a composite primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, what *is* a Customer Product? This looks like a standard Sales Order model.

Don't make it a simple Many-To-Many relationship. Use One-To-Many on both sides. You're on the right track, though I don't see your Quantity field anywhere.

A Customer hasMany CustomerProducts. A Product hasMany CustomerProducts. A CustomerProduct belongsTo a Customer and belongsTo a Product.

If you want to use an auto-generated id field, then that is your primary key. You can add a unique constraint on (customer,product) if you don't want duplicate lines by customer and product.

Comment: thanks it was very clear. but for many-to-many relashioship without a extra column the best is to make like this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example-annotation/) and create no auto-generated id field (pseudo-key) ?

Comment: Hibernate recommends using meaningless surrogate keys most of the time, so I would go with that as a default choice.