# Hibernate - optimizing ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I need help with Hibernate and many-to-many relationship. Here is my sample schema on this [link](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/blob/master/src/test/resources/db/schema.sql). It's simple enough so you can easily get the point. Concentration is on tables `PERSON`, `ADDRESS` and `PERSON_ADDRESS`.

Java model is here on this [link](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/tree/master/src/main/java/me/business/model). My questions are:

- Is it totally wrong to have that class `PersonAddress`?
- If I leave it like that what are the problems I could encounter with, at some later stage of development?
- How can I optimize it?

Git repo with my sample code is [here](https://github.com/slavisah/mybusiness/).

Comment: You don't have a plain M-N relation. It's an M-N with extra attributes on the relation, hence introducing an intermediate class (as you have done) and having two 1-N relations is the correct thing to do. So why not actually use it? You have no "problem" in this post.

Comment: What if I want to have collection of addresses in Person and collection of persons in Address? Is there need to avoid `private Collection<PersonAddress> personAddressCollection`?

Answer (score 0):

Class `PersonAddress` is called join table. Hibernate supports join table and you don't need additional effort to achive it. But I'm not sure if you can add additional properties into join table. [Hiberante bidirectional association](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-join)

For additional properties on your join table you should go with @Embeddable and @EmbeddedId annotations, but then most of the joining work you will do on your own, look at this answer, [Hiberante additional properties in join table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table#answer-10301484)