# org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm implemented this solution for many to many with exstra fields : [Many to Many Hibernate Mapping for additional property in the join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294338/many-to-many-hibernate-mapping-for-additional-property-in-the-join-table/10301484#10301484)

My code:

```
@Entity
public class User {


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;

  }

@Entity
public class Role {


    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pk.role", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<UserRole> userRoles;
}

@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({ @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.user", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "pk.role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")) })
public class UserRole{

    private UserRoleId pk;


    public UserRole(User user, Role role) {

    super();
    this.pk = new UserRoleId(
                 user, role);
    }


    public UserRole() {

    super();
    }


    public Long getUserId() {

    return this.pk.getUser().getId();
    }


    @EmbeddedId
    public UserRoleId getPk() {

    return pk;
    }


    public void setPk(UserRoleId pk) {

    this.pk = pk;
    }


    public User getUser() {

    return this.pk.getUser();
    }


    public Role getRole() {

    return this.pk.getRole();
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Embeddable
public class UserRoleId implements Serializable {

    private User user;
    private Role role;


    public UserRoleId() {

    super();
    }


    public UserRoleId(User user, Role role) {

    super();
    this.user = user;
    this.role = role;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    public User getUser() {

    return user;
    }


    public void setUser(User user) {

    this.user = user;
    }


    @ManyToOne
    public Role getRole() {

    return role;
    }


    public void setRole(Role role) {

    this.role = role;
    }

}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.xxx.model.entities.User, at table: UserRole, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the getUser function in UserRole entity.

Comment: Your guess is right. Annotate it with @Transient. Why do you make your own life complex by using composite primary keys? It would be much simpler to have a purely technical, auto-generated, single-column ID in the UserRole entity.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the same question as you, and I solved it through moving the annotation to the front of corresponding get method.